# Buscar los datos que inicien con el mismo carácter en una lista Python

Tags: python, array

Tengo un archivo de texto que contiene tres datos por persona: nombre, documento y teléfono, están todo separados por salto de línea así:

```
PEPE
1
1
PABLO
2
2
LUIS
3
3
```

los guardo en una lista de la siguiente forma:

```
arch = open('agenda.txt', 'r')
    for linea in arch:
        arreglo.append(linea.rstrip())
    arch.close()
```

Lo que necesito ahora es generar una nueva lista que me muestre los datos solamente de las personas que la primera letra del nombre sea iguales, por ejemplo si quisiera solo de la lista los datos delos que el nombre inicia con P la lista nueva debería darme solo:

```
PEPE
1
1
PABLO
2
2
```

Los nombres no están en orden alfabético, no se si así se haga mas fácil la búsqueda pero la lista la pase a una matriz así:

```
x=int(len(arreglo)/3)
matriz=array(arreglo).reshape(x,3)
```

Comment: cada persona solo tendrá 2 datos? (ósea los que se muestran abajo)

Comment: si, cada persona tendra solo dos datos, siempre va a ser (nombre, documento,telefono)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una solución:

```
with open("agenda.txt", "r") as agenda:
    lista = [y for y in map(lambda x: x.rstrip(), agenda.readlines())]
    letra = 'P'
    final = [lista[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(lista), 3) if lista[i][0] == letra]
    print(final)
```

Con `agenda.readlines()` lee todo el contenido del archivo como una lista de lineas. Cada línea termina con un `\n`, que eliminamos usando `rstrip`. Para aplicar la función a cada elemento de la lista, usamos `map`, que recibe una función *definida por el usuario* y un iterable.

El iterable es la lista devuelta por `readlines`. Para la función definimos una función anónima (lambda) que recibe como argumento la línea a examinar, y le aplica `rstrip`.

Con todo lo anterior, y aplicando comprensión de listas, obtenemos finalmente una lista de líneas sin los `\n` al final.

Para formar la lista solicitada, recorremos las líneas de tres en tres (usando `range`). Si la primera línea del grupo (`list[i][0]`) comienza con la letra indicada, se extrae una rebanada de tres elementos (`lista[i:i+3]`), que se agrega a la lista final:

```
with open("agenda.txt", "r") as agenda:
    lista = [y for y in map(lambda x: x.rstrip(), agenda.readlines())]
    letra = 'P'
    final = [lista[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(lista), 3) if lista[i][0] == letra]
    print(final)
```

*agenda.txt*

```
1
1
PABLO
2
2
LUIS
3
3
```

produce

```
[['PEPE', '1', '1'], ['PABLO', '2', '2']]
```

**Edición**

En un formato más *humano*, podemos imprimir la lista usando:

```
print('\n'.join(item for sublist in final for item in sublist))
```

obteniendo los datos en el mismo formato del original:

```
PEPE
1
1
PABLO
2
2
```

Comment: me fue de mucha ayuda, pero me puedes ayudar en como imprimir el resultado solo los valores separadas por salto de linea? asi como el txt original

Comment: @lycros. Agregue lo pedido a la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Bueno para hacer lo que quieres tendremos que apoyarnos de una expresión regular para encontrar las coincidencias y también usaremos un ciclo `for`, aun que en mi caso hare uso de una comprensión de lista, que es lo mismo pero mas abreviado

```py
import re

arreglo = []
with open('texto.txt', 'r') as arch:
    for linea in arch:
        arreglo.append(linea.rstrip())

#print(arreglo)
```

Bien hasta ahi todo bien, ahora tendremos que crear una expresión regular, en mi caso lo hago de esta forma `re.compile()` como parámetro le pasaremos nuestra expresión regular, en este caso seria que coincida con cualquier palabra que empiece  por X letra, para eso hacemos la siguiente expresión `^P`, el signo `^` significa
*empiece por ..* en este caso `P` (aun que podemos indicar cualquier letra de forma dinámica)

```py
letra = "P" #esto puede ser obtenido por un input
regex = re.compile(f"^{letra}") #utilizamos f-string para pasarle la letra
```

Bien ahora solo buscamos, para eso tendremos que recorrer la lista `arreglo`

```py
resultado = [arreglo[arreglo.index(p):arreglo.index(p)+3] for p in arreglo[::3] if regex.findall(p)]
print(resultado)
```

Esta comprensión de lista hace lo siguiente: rrecorre la lista y agrega como elemento una lista `[nombre,documento,telefono]` (`arreglo[arreglo.index(p):arreglo.index(p)+3]`) solo si cumple con la expresión regular.
**resultado**

```
[['PEPE', '1', '1'], ['PABLO', '2', '2']]
```

Seguro habrás notado esto `arreglo[::3]` esto se hace para no validar todos los elementos solo los que están en posiciones `i*3`, veamos lo que pasa.

```py
resultado = [p for p in arreglo[::3]]
print(resultado)
```

**resultado**

```
['PEPE', 'PABLO', 'LUIS']
```

Eso significa que solo evaluaremos estos datos, mas no los otros.

Answer (score 0):

```
#-*- coding: utf -8 -*-
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

es más simple usar un dataframe de pandas para buscar la subcadena

```
with open('agenda.txt') as archivo:
    lista = [linea.rstrip() for linea in archivo]
```

para leer el archivo y por medio de comprensión de listas guardar la lista

```
x=len(lista)//3
matriz=np.array(lista).reshape(x,3)
```

ya convertimos a matriz bidimensional

```
df= pd.DataFrame(matriz,columns=["Nombre","Doc","Tel"])
```

creamos un dataframe con columnas de los datos

```
inicial = df.iloc[np.where(df.Nombre.str.contains("P"))]
```

ahora buscamos con where en la columna nombre algún valor con la subcadena "P"

Mostramos

```
print(inicial)
```

Resultado:

```
Nombre Doc Tel
0   PEPE   1   1
1  PABLO   2   2
```

este método me parece el más simple pero tiene un gran problema y es que encontrará cualquier nombre que contenga "P" sin importar el lugar que ocupe, y tus nombres están todos en mayúsculas así que habrá que dejar solo la primer letra en mayúsculas por eso sería conveniente cambiar el formato de los nombres con:

```
df['Nombre'] = df['Nombre'].str.capitalize()
```

ahora si será mejor para buscar

```
inicial = df.iloc[np.where(df.Nombre.str.contains("P"))]
```

Resultado ahora:

```
 Nombre Doc Tel
0   Pepe   1   1
1  Pablo   2   2
```